# join array field with ANY

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Trying to join based on the ID of A that has at least one of the IDSs of table B. A.ID is of type varchar, B.IDS(which is converted as set) is of type varchar[]. I tried like below, but I get an error.

```
create.select()
    .from(A)
    .join(B)
    .on(A.ID.equal(any(B.IDS))) // Cannot resolve method 'equal(QuantifiedSelect<Record1<T>>)'
    .where(other conditions)
```

Correct jooq code matching below query.

```
select A.ID, B.ID from A a, B b where a.id = ANY(b.ids) and (other conditions)
```

Comment: What you've seemed to describe is that each row in A should join on Every row in B, provided that at least one id matches. Which makes no sense to me. Please give a concrete example to demonstrate the behaviour you need. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: expand to each row is what i want to do.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a concrete Example, as per the help page I linked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be in this part of your question:

> B.IDS(which is converted as set) is of type varchar[]

I'm assuming, you used a [data type converter](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-types/) to turn your `Field<T[]>` into a `Field<Set<T>>`? While that is useful for projecting "better" types than the out of the box types jOOQ supports, it will prevent you from using some data type specific API, in this case array specific API, including the [`DSL.any(Field<T[]>)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#any(org.jooq.Field)) operator.

You have at least three options to work around this in this specific case:

- Coerce the type back to `String[]` using [`DSL.coerce()`](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/datatype-coercions/)
- Use [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), which is always a useful workaround when running into some limitation
- Use rawtype casts to remove type safety

Answer (score 0):

Would this do the trick?

(I assume the two table are SQL tables)

```
SELECT a.ID
FROM A AS a 
WHERE a.ID IN (SELECT ID FROM B)
```